# BLE - Sum of preceding bytes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I need to work on a Bluetooth hardware and need to send the bytes data. I know the format but not sure about the last byte:-

[0x6E,0x01,0x00,0x24,**0x93**]

The last byte is the - byte5(verify). The preceding bytes add up, but I am not sure how value 93 came up.

Is there any specific logic that needs to be added for this.

Comment: 0x93 is actually 147 which is the sum of the first 4 bytes (110, 1, 0, 36)

Comment: To add to what Leo said, the strange prefix before the digits is really important. 0x indicates Hecadecimal base/digits. 0d is decimal (aka “numbers as we all know them “) and 0b is binary

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus 
how I can calculate and get that in [UInt8] as I need to send total 5 bytes in swift.